# Read files from a local folder and assign a video or img tag with php

Tags: php, html, if-statement, foreach

I'm trying to read some files from a local folder and make an array with it. Then I need to assign to every file an "img" or "video" tag according to the file. To read the files from the folder and make an array I'm using this working code:

```
<?php
   $dir = 'video/';
   $dh  = opendir($dir);
    while (false !== ($fileName = readdir($dh))) {
       $ext = substr($fileName, strrpos($fileName, '.') + 1);
       if(in_array($ext, array("jpg","jpeg","png","gif","mp4")))
          $files1[] = $fileName;
   }
?>
```

The problem starts with the next step. I'm using "foreach" and "if" but is not working:

```
            <?php
            foreach($files1 as $fileName) 
            {
               if ($ext == "jpg") 
                 { ?>
                   <img  src="video/<?php echo $fileName; ?>"/>
                  <?php } 
               else if ($ext =="mp4")
                { ?>
                  <video><source src="video/<?php echo $fileName; ?>"></video>  
             <?php }
             }
            ?>
```

When I run this code, it tag  all the files (including the mp4 files) with the "img" tag.

What Am i doing wrong?

Comment: You have to calculate value for your `$ext` variable in the `foreach` loop too. You seem to use its last value from `while` loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `if/else` above only has two possible conditions - either `jpg` or `mp4` ( unless there are more conditions not shown ) which might be the issue. Alternatively you could try along these lines ( not tested )

```
$dir = 'video/';
$col = preg_grep( '@(\.jpg$|\.jpeg$|\.png$|\.gif$|\.mp4$)@i', glob( $dir . '*.*' ) );
if( count( $col ) > 0 ){
    foreach( $col as $file ){

        $filename=pathinfo( $file, PATHINFO_BASENAME );

        switch( strtolower( pathinfo( $file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION ) ) ){
            case 'jpg':
            case 'png':
            case 'gif':
            case 'jpeg':
                /* image */
                echo "<img  src='video/$filename' />";
            break;

            case 'mp4':
                /* video */
                echo "<video><source src='video/$filename'></video> ";
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi RamRaider, this solution works perfect!! Thank you! Now I need to jump to the next step. Im building a Slider with videos and images and i need to add some javascript code, but i can't paste the code here, so Im gonna open another question, so if you can help I will appreciate it a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Here is my working version. Using 'glob()' which grabs the contents of a directory as an array. Using finfo tools you can get the mimetype. Be aware that both the mimetype and extension can be forged, so if these are user generated files you'll want to do additional validation. I also made the $files1 into a multi-dimensional array containing the mimetype and absolute file path. Hope this helps.

```
<?php
// The full path to the directory we are grabbing the contents of.
$dir = __DIR__.'/videos/*';
$dh  = glob($dir);

$finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
foreach ($dh as $key => $fileName) {
    $fileMime = finfo_file($finfo, $fileName);
    if (in_array($fileMime, array("image/jpg","image/jpeg","image/png","image/gif","video/mp4"))) {
        // Create the array and remove the __DIR__ path from the file to get the html friendly absolute path.
        $files1[] = ['file' => str_replace(__DIR__, '', $fileName), 'mime' => $filedata];
    }
}

finfo_close($finfo);
?>
<?php

foreach ($files1 as $data) {
    // We know it is an image b/c it is not video/mp4
    if ($data['mime'] != "video/mp4") { ?>
        <img  src="<?php echo $data['file']; ?>"/>
    <?php } else { ?>
       <video><source src="<?php echo $data['file']; ?>"></video>
    <?php }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I made something similar few days ago, jpg and csv was my case. However, you can solve it (I think) by changing your `IF` conditions.

```
 ...
 foreach($files1 as $fileName)             { 

$file_parts = pathinfo($value); 

            if (in_array("jpg", $file_parts)) {

....
```